# How to test 2 different links with same text?

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver

I was testing if the link exists on a web page. For that I am testing if that particular text for ex `"Selenium Videos"` is in `<a></a>` tag or not. But there are  two same links such as --`"How to Master QTP?"` on the page one in menus and second in `Recent free LIVE webinars` on right hand side of the page. I don't know how to test these two different links having same link text. Using the function written below, it will return true if I am searching second link text but it will find first link text. Please help.

I am using following function to test links.

```
public static String checkLink(WebDriver driver,String linkText)
    {
        //purpose : check if the link for text is available 
        //ip: driver,xPath,Data
        try
        {

        List <WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for(WebElement we : links) 
        {
           if(linkText.equals(we.getText())) 
           {
                System.out.println("Link text from excel is:" + linkText);
                System.out.println("Link text from element is:" + we.getText());

              return "Pass";
           }//if
        }//for
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "Fail";
    }//catch
    return "Fail";
}//enter text
```

Comment: Does it need to fot for 1 specific website??? If so, can you provide the link to that website?

Comment: @user1177636 You're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xpath and include either a parent or sibling element in xpath. You mentioned two different labels or desc     you can use these in xpath

Comment: Thanks you all. I added xPath in that function and I could locate those links.

Comment: Honestly, how the hell do you get that from the question?  I could understand if the answer was use an appropriate locator but why specifically an XPath?  Why do you need to include a parent or sibling in the XPath?  How can you know without any HTML?